# Binding DataGridViewComboBoxColumn to DataTable is not working

Tags: c#, winforms

I am binding `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to `DataTable`, but the the cells of the column are not displaying the bound table.
any idea?
to test the `DataTable`, I bound it to a normal `ComboBox` and this shows the expected behavior.

```
 private void populateDataGW()
    {
        int addressesCount = data.Length / 186;
        TestingAdrress[] addressArray = new TestingAdrress[addressesCount];
        addressArray = getArray();
        DataGridViewRow dtRow = new DataGridViewRow();

        dtTableCmbBx = getAllCustomers();
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmBxCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        //Binding here is not working
        cmBxCol.DataSource = dtTableCmbBx;
        cmBxCol.ValueMember = "Customer_ID";
        cmBxCol.DisplayMember = "Name";
        dtGrViTestAddress.Columns.Add(cmBxCol);
        //code for "normal" combobox
        comboBox1.DataSource = dtTableCmbBx;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember= "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Customer_ID";

        DataGridViewButtonCell btnCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
        btnCell.Value = "Hinzufügen";

        for (int i=0; i< addressArray.Length;i++)
        {
            dtGrViTestAddress.Rows.Add();
            dtGrViTestAddress.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = addressArray[i].Name;
            dtGrViTestAddress.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = addressArray[i].Street;
            dtGrViTestAddress.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = addressArray[i].PostalCode;
            dtGrViTestAddress.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = addressArray[i].City;
            dtGrViTestAddress.Rows[i].Cells[5] = btnCell;                
        }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: As I see you have not set a value for your last column, also You don't need to use button cell this way :`dtGrViTestAddress.Rows[i].Cells[5] = btnCell;` just add it like other columns and set it's value. The other thing you should know is, you can bind the whole `DataGridView` to a data source and avoid adding rows manually.

Comment: that is not the problem. the problem is in cmBxCol..

Comment: i dont have a datasource, it is some values wich is given from user. and that is not causing problem.

Comment: Where did you set the value for the last column? I don't see any code that set the value for that column. You can click on ComboBox and set the value.

Comment: that is exact my problem. when i click on the comboBox cell "cmBxCol" nothing happens. as if there is no data bound to it.

Comment: Have you tried clicking a couple (2-3) times until the combo list opens? Combo boxes work differently when hosted in grid cells. Are you saying you get an empty list?

Comment: there is no list the combo box. exactly, there is even no empty item, as the normal combo box usualy show, when they are empty. and i tried your tipp to click several times, but nothing happend.

Comment: Are you sure `getAllCustomers` is returning valid data? Are you sure you're actually calling `populateDataGW` somewhere?

Comment: yes, i added the other combox in the bottom of the form only to test that returned datatable is valid. and as you can see, it is working with the other combobox.

Comment: @Orientos We don't need pictures, but a code that we can copy/paste, run and see what you mean. The code that you provided does not meet that criteria, so I don't see how you can get help.

Comment: okay, i attached the code, but you have to have your own database to test it

Comment: your "button cell" should be column `[4]` and your combobox column should be `[5]`, so "button cell" column is overwriting your combobox column, i think....

Answer (score 1):

i found the problem. i wanted the datagridview to be readOnly, so thats why the combobox didnt show the items in it, now i changed this property, and i set it for each column separated, and let the comboboxcolumn to be readOnly=false

Answer (score 0):

> **Method 1:** Use Linq

```
var details = (from x in db.Details
               orderby x.Datetime descending
               where x.RaisedBy == "xyz"
               select x).ToList();

comboBox1.ValueMember ="id";
comboBox1.DataSource = details;

comboBox2.ValueMember ="Name";
comboBox2.DataSource = details;

comboBox3.ValueMember ="Street";
comboBox3.DataSource = details;

comboBox4.ValueMember ="PostalCode";
comboBox4.DataSource = details;
```

> **Method :2**

```
var combocolumnA = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combocolumnA.HeaderText = "ID"; // grid header name
combocolumnA.ValueMember = "id";// database Column name
combocolumnA.DataSource = details;
GV.Columns.Add(combocolumnA);
combocolumnA.Width = 100;

var combocolumnB = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combocolumnB.HeaderText = "Name";
combocolumnB.ValueMember = "Name";
combocolumnB.DataSource = details;
GV.Columns.Add(combocolumnB);
combocolumnB.Width = 150;
```

---

**Edit:**

Just to tell you one more thing... If you want the data in grid view suppose when you select name from combo box then data automatically change all fields of gridview according to database ?